# Show that the 3-color problem is in P when the input graph is a tree.

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, coloring, np-complete

This one is from university assignment. I am completely stuck on this one and I searched the internet but couldn't find a explanation.

> Show that the 3-color problem is in P when the input graph is a tree.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Every tree is $2$-colorable, so I'm not quite getting the question.

Comment: yeah I know but thats what the question states. I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** following a suggestion in the comments.

1. Validate that the input is a tree
2. Answer "yes"

Both (1) and (2) are doable in polynomial time (how?) so this is in $P$

Comment: Does this prove that 3-color is in P? 2-coloring can be done by BFS and tree is a bipartite by definition. But what about 3-color?

Comment: @semal259 any 2-coloring is also a 3-coloring, so it does indeed prove that 3-coloring a tree is in $P$

Comment: One could argue that it's even simpler than this, since the $2$-color problem should have a yes/no answer. Just write a program that always produces the answer yes (possibly after verifying that the input is a tree.)

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip :-) +1, funny, yes, definitely

Comment: Is a tree k-colorable then?

Comment: @semal259 Indeed, a tree is $k$-colorable in polynomial time for all $k \ge 2$.

Comment: alright! got it! thanks!